# script para criptografar textos

Tags: c

Venho tentando criar um programa em c para criptografar um texto, mas ainda estou aprendendo muitos comandos em c.

Até o momento criei um string "char text[200]" pra guardar meu texto. Depois criei dois arquivos .txt. um com as letras em ordem e outro do jeito que desejo criptografar.

ex:
arq1
"a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"

arq2
"z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a"

Assim, onde for 'a' vira 'z', 'b' vira 'y', etc..

imaginei que poderia comparar cada letra do texto com a letra do arq1 e depois dizer q equivale ao arq2.

ex:
c = arq1[2], logo ele verifica no arq2[2] e diz q 'c' receberá 'x'

minha dificuldade é comparar esses arquivos pois comecei a ver agora o basico do fopen e fclose.

imagino que eu possa fazer isso +- assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char text[200];
int i;
int j=0;
...
scanf("%s",text);

 for(i=0;i<(int)text;i++)
 {
 While(text[i]=!arq1[j])
  {
   j++; 
  }
  if(text[i]==arq1[j])
  {
   text[i]=arq2[j];
  }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida exatamente? Outra coisa, isto que você está querendo não é uma criptografia, é uma substituição apenas. Inclusive muito fácil de se desvendar.

Comment: minha dúvida seria como identificar cada letra do meu texto e substituir de acordo com a minha tabela. tem algum comando específico ? pois ainda estou muito "cru" em c.

Comment: Não seria mais fazer tudo isso num arquivo só?